# Neo4j/Node.js : retrieve data by http endpoint

Tags: node.js, neo4j

I'm trying to retrieve some data from the neo4j http transaction endpoint, and I'm able to print the result, but not to store the data into a variable.

```
var http = require("http");
var r = require("request");

var txUrl = "http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit";

function cypher(query) {
  r.post({  uri:txUrl,
            json:{
              statements:[{
                statement:query
              }]
            },
          },
          function(error,response,body){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(body));
          }
       );
}

var query = "MATCH (n:Groups) RETURN n.name";

function process_request(req,res){
    var body = JSON.stringify({name:"Test"});
  //body = cypher(query);
    var content_length = body.length;
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Length': content_length,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });
    res.end(body);
}

var s = http.createServer(process_request);
s.listen(8080);
```

For the moment I don't want to use some others neo4j javascript library, but just store the json result in a var and print it as application/json in my browser.

Anyone can help ?

Answer (score 0):

Your cypher function doesn't return anything ... and the nodejs request is using callback functions.

So you need something like that :

```
var http = require("http");
var r = require("request");

var txUrl = "http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit";

function cypher(query, callback) {
  r.post({  uri:txUrl,
            json:{
              statements:[{
                statement:query
              }]
            },
          },
          function(error,response,body){
            callback(JSON.stringify(body));
          }
       );
}

var query = "MATCH (n:Groups) RETURN n.name";

function process_request(req,res){

    var callback = function(data) {
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Length': content_length,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        });
        res.end(data);
    }
    cypher(query, callback);

}

var s = http.createServer(process_request);
s.listen(8080);
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response.
As a newbie I didn't get very well how callbacks works, but now it's a little bit clear.

Your code didn't function, but I post here the solution : using Promises.
It exists "request-promise-native" module which handle everything for you.
So, ths code is OK :

```
var http = require("http");
var rp = require("request-promise-native");

var txUrl = "http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit";
var query = "MATCH (n:Groupe) RETURN n";
var options = {
  method: 'POST',
  uri: txUrl,
  body: {
    statements:[{
      statement:query
    }]
  },
  json: true
};

function process_request(req,res){
  rp(options)
    .then(function(parsedBody){
      var data = JSON.stringify(parsedBody);
      console.log(data);
      var content_length = Buffer.byteLength(data);
      res.writeHead(200, {
              'Content-Length': content_length,
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      });
      res.end(data);
    })
    .catch(function(err){
      var catch_error = JSON.stringify({error: err});
      console.log(catch_error);
      res.end(catch_error);
    });
}

var s = http.createServer(process_request);
s.listen(8080);
```